# Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, sikuli, cucumber-serenity

Chrome Version: 102.0.5005.115
Chrome Driver version: 102.0.5005.61 (32 bit)

I am getting the following error after adding sikuliX dependency in my pom.xml. I have no clue on why issue arises when sikuliX dependency is added.

```
Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

**Step definition file:**

```
package foo.boo

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import net.thucydides.core.annotations.Step;
import net.thucydides.core.pages.PageObject;


public class login extends PageObject {
   

    public login() throws SQLException {
    }

    @Step
    @Given("^Login with valid \"([^\"]*)\" credentials$")
    public void login_with_valid_credentials(String userType) throws InterruptedException {
        open();   --> place where issue araises.
# piece of code
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>fooboo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>fooboo</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>2.6.0</serenity.version>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.29</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0-alpha10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.sukgu</groupId>
            <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sikulix</groupId>
            <artifactId>sikulixapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                   
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>serenity-reports</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aggregate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>auto-clean</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>foo/boo</directory>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Note: The code works fine without sikuliX dependency.

**Error Messages:-**

```
Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'
System info: host: 'fooboo', ip: '192.168.0.177', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_311'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, base.url: https://digitalexpert-dev.e..., browserName: chrome, chrome.driver: Types/UserInterface/Drivers..., edge.driver: Types/UserInterface/Drivers..., goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}}]). See below for more details.
        at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.newWebdriverInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:146)
        at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newDriverInstance(WebDriverFacade.java:141)
        at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newProxyDriver(WebDriverFacade.java:132)
        at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.getProxiedDriver(WebDriverFacade.java:102)
        at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.get(WebDriverFacade.java:172)
        at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject.openPageAtUrl(PageObject.java:981)
        at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject.open(PageObject.java:879)
        at net.serenitybdd.core.pages.PageObject.open(PageObject.java:867)
        at BusinessComponents.ClinicalPortal.Users.UserOrg.UserInterface.Pages.CommonAuth.StepDefinitionFiles.UI_CommonAuth_SDF.login_with_valid_credentials(UI_CommonAuth_SDF.java:24)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.doInvoke(Invoker.java:66)
        at io.cucumber.java.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:24)
        at io.cucumber.java.AbstractGlueDefinition.invokeMethod(AbstractGlueDefinition.java:47)
        at io.cucumber.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:29)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.CoreStepDefinition.execute(CoreStepDefinition.java:66)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:63)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:92)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:64)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:51)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:104)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:73)
        at io.cucumber.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:151)
        at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:135)
        at io.cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at io.cucumber.junit.CucumberSerenityRunner.runChild(CucumberSerenityRunner.java:259)
        at io.cucumber.junit.CucumberSerenityRunner.runChild(CucumberSerenityRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
        at io.cucumber.junit.CucumberSerenityRunner$RunCucumber.evaluate(CucumberSerenityRunner.java:287)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:377)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:284)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:248)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:167)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:456)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:169)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:595)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:581)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '4.0.0', revision: '3a21814679'
System info: host: 'G17SW4B3E', ip: '192.168.0.177', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_311'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, base.url: https://foo.e..., browserName: chrome, chrome.driver: Types/UserInterface/Drivers..., edge.driver: Types/UserInterface/Drivers..., goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}}}]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:577)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:246)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:168)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:104)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:91)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:80)
        at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.ChromeDriverProvider.lambda$newInstance$0(ChromeDriverProvider.java:66)
        at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.ProvideNewDriver.withConfiguration(ProvideNewDriver.java:40)
        at net.serenitybdd.core.webdriver.driverproviders.ChromeDriverProvider.newInstance(ChromeDriverProvider.java:62)
        at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.createWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:157)
        at net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFactory.newWebdriverInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:136)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: NettyHttpHandler request execution error
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:51)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:102)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:164)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:139)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:559)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.handler.codec.compression.Brotli
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1928)
        at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:66)
        ... 76 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.handler.codec.compression.Brotli
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecompressor.newContentDecoder(HttpContentDecompressor.java:70)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.decode(HttpContentDecoder.java:100)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.decode(HttpContentDecoder.java:47)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:321)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:308)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:422)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with sikulix version. It works from after downgrading from 2.0.5 to 2.0.4.